# pandas fill NA based on merge with another dataframe

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I already posted this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-rows) but since there is no response, I thought I will also post this here

```
stud_name   act_qtr year    yr_qty  qtr mov_avg_full    mov_avg_2qtr_min_period
0   ABC Q2  2014    2014Q2  NaN NaN NaN
1   ABC Q1  2016    2016Q1  Q1  13.0    14.5
2   ABC Q4  2016    2016Q4  NaN NaN NaN
3   ABC Q4  2017    2017Q4  NaN NaN NaN
4   ABC Q4  2020    2020Q4  NaN NaN NaN

OP = pd.read_clipboard()

stud_name   qtr year    t_score p_score yr_qty  mov_avg_full    mov_avg_2qtr_min_period
0   ABC Q1  2014    10  11  2014Q1  10.000000   10.0
1   ABC Q1  2015    11  32  2015Q1  10.500000   10.5
2   ABC Q2  2015    13  45  2015Q2  11.333333   12.0
3   ABC Q3  2015    15  32  2015Q3  12.250000   14.0
4   ABC Q4  2015    17  21  2015Q4  13.200000   16.0
5   ABC Q1  2016    12  56  2016Q1  13.000000   14.5
6   ABC Q2  2017    312 87  2017Q2  55.714286   162.0
7   ABC Q3  2018    24  90  2018Q3  51.750000   168.0

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

I would like to fillna() based on below logic

For ex: let's take `stud_name = ABC`. He has multipple NA records. Let's take his `NA` for `2020Q4`. To fill that, we pick the latest record from `df` for `stud_name=ABC` before `2020Q4`  (which is 2018Q3). Similarly, if we take `stud_name = ABC`. His another `NA` record is for `2014Q2`. We pick the latest (prior) record from `df` for `stud_name=ABC` before `2014Q2` (which is 2014Q1). We need to sort based on `yearqty` values to get the latest (prior) record correctly

We need to do this for each `stud_name` and for a big dataset

So, we fillna in `mov_avg_full` and `mov_avg_2qtr_min_period`

**If there are no previous records to look at in df dataframe, leave NA as it is**

I was trying something like below but it doesn't work and incorrect

```
Filled = OP.merge(df,on=['stud_name'],how='left')
filled.sort_values(['year','Qty'],inplace=True)
filled['mov_avg_full'].fillna(Filled.groupby('stud_name']['mov_avg_full'].shift())
filled['mov_avg_2qtr_min_period'].fillna(Filled .groupby('stud_name']['mov_avg_2qtr_min_period'].shift())
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]